# How to assign a value to a button with a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set a value to a submit button using a variable.

```
<form action="/HouseRentalManagementPortal/More_Info" method = "post">
    <button type = submit name="id" value = __X__ >More Info</button>
</form>
```

So in this code, I am assigning a value to a button. But I want to assign a variable value like if **X** is a variable and it has a value as 5. But it always takes it as a string "**X**", not a variable.

Comment: You have tagged your question with `javascript` - where is the related code?

Comment: You want to assign a variable so that the value of the button updates when you change the variable? This is not quite possible

Comment: First try to do it on your own

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('moreInfoButton').setAttribute('value', x);
```

(Assuming your button has this particular id)